# python pandas adding 2 dataframe with specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe the one looks like this :

```
      Date     id    name    amount    period   
2011-06-30      1       A     10000         1
2011-06-30      2       B     10000         1
2011-06-30      3       C     10000         1
```

And another one looks like this :

```
id   amount    period   
 1    10000         1
 3    10000         0
```

And the result that i want looks like this :

```
id     amount    period   
 1      20000         2
 2      10000         1
 3      20000         1
```

How can i do that in python pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with filtered columns with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1[['id','amount','period']], df2]).groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   id  amount  period
0   1   20000       2
1   2   10000       1
2   3   20000       1
```

EDIT:

If need subtract by `id` create index for `id` and then use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df11 = df1[['id','amount','period']].set_index('id')
df22 = df2.set_index('id')

df3 = df11.sub(df22, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df3)
   id   amount  period
0   1      0.0     0.0
1   2  10000.0     1.0
2   3      0.0     1.0
```

Comment: but how if i have other calculation like substract or whatever?